# Angular2 displaying http get response in component

Tags: angular, servicestack, angular2-services, angular2-components

I am building my first angular2 app and this is my very first service call. I am using service stack API. the GET call returns a IEnumerable This  call is working by itself, when plugged into my angular service the status comes back as 200 and I can see in the browser the actual response thats returned. however when this response is setup to be shown as a li item in the component.html, it doesn't show them. instead it only displays the bullet indicating that got the list item but there is some problem with the way the response is handled.

Category.service.ts code is as below:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoryDTO } from './Category';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class CategoryService {

  constructor(private _http: Http) { }

  getCategoriesFromApi(): Observable<CategoryDTO[]> {
    return this._http.get("http://localhost:53426/category/find")
                     .map((response: Response) => <CategoryDTO[]> response.json());
    }
   /**
    *
   getCategoriesFromApi(): Category[] {
     return [{ id: '123', name: 'Apparel' }];
   }*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

category.component.ts is as below

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoryDTO } from './Category';
import { CategoryService } from './category.service';
import { DataserviceService } from '../dataservice.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'show-category',
  templateUrl: './category.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./category.component.css']
})
export class CategoryComponent implements OnInit {

  categoriesToDisplay: CategoryDTO[];
  constructor(private categoryService: CategoryService) { }

  getCatsToDisplay(): void {
  /**
   * this.categoriesToDisplay = this.categoryService.getCategoriesFromApi();
   */
    this.categoryService.getCategoriesFromApi()
      .subscribe((categoriesReturned) => this.categoriesToDisplay = categoriesReturned , err => console.log('err = ' + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2)));
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCatsToDisplay();
  }

  /**
   * public values: Category[];
   constructor(private _dataService: DataserviceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._dataService
      .getAll<Category[]>()
      .subscribe((data: Category[]) => this.values = data);
   */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

category.component.html is as below

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let category of categoriesToDisplay">
    <span>{{category.name}}</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The CategoryDTO typescript class (Category.ts) is this:

```
export class CategoryDTO {
    id: string;
    name: string;
}
```

And finally the API call to get all categories is this:

```
public IEnumerable<CategoryDTO> Get(FindCategory request)
    {
        var entities = this.Db.Select<Category>().OrderBy(c => c.Name);
        return this.Mapper.Map<List<CategoryDTO>>(entities);
    }
```

And the output I see is this
[output on the browser just shows that there is a list item but doesn't display the category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkETu.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your properties start with a capital letter `Id` & `Name`

You need to update your angular code to use the correct properties.

```
export class CategoryDTO {
    Id: string;
    Name: string;
}

<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let category of categoriesToDisplay">
        <span>{{category.Name}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much. thought about the case being different. Didn't know its case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Hang on! I've figured out some problems of my own and this doesn't seem to be quite it. It's likely, as LLai said, that it's because your properties have their first letters capitalized!

<strike>Might be a bit strange, but changing</strike>

```
this.categoryService.getCategoriesFromApi()
  .subscribe((categoriesReturned) => this.categoriesToDisplay = categoriesReturned , err => console.log('err = ' + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2)));
```

to

```
this.categoriesToDisplay = this.categoryService.getCategoriesFromApi()
  .subscribe((categoriesReturned) => this.categoriesToDisplay = categoriesReturned , err => console.log('err = ' + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2)));
```

could possibly do the trick. I've had this same problem, and the solution was just to assign the variable I wanted to change to the api call in addition changing that same variable in the subscription. I should also clarify that in my code, I didn't give a type for my variable (i.e. my variable is simply `public variable`, which is not ideal and I'm still search for solutions.) Hope this helps and good luck!

(I'm still fairly new Angular, so if anyone could explain why this works that'd be lovely.Thank you!)

Comment: `.subscribe()` returns a [Subscription](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subscription.js~Subscription.html). In this case we want `categoriesToDisplay` to be an array, so this will not work. You may be thinking of the case where you store the observable in a variable (no .subscribe), then use the async pipe to handle the subscribing. so the html would look something like `*ngFor="let category of categoriesToDisplay | async"`

Comment: Indeed! Which is why I'm confused as to why my code works. I also do similar api calls to grab an array from my backend and assign it to a variable. However I've only found success with the following:

`this.array = this.http.get(endpoint).subscribe(res => this.array = res)`

Very strange!

Comment: If you type array as `array: any[]` you will see typescript throw an error `Cannot assign type Subscription to type any[]`. In this case there should be no need for `this.array =`

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense! In my code, I don't specify the type of my array; I simply have `public array;`.

Comment: Aha! @LLai thanks for discussing with me! I've figured out why I was having my problem: most of our backend is stored in arrays... except for the one thing that I've been having problems with. This one's actually an object. Changing my variable declaration to `public array: any = {}` was the key. Cheers!